# Python, How to fill between multiple (4) curves?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

```
fig = plt.figure(num=1)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

def f1(x):
    return 1/x
def f2(x):
  return 2/x
def f3(x):
  return np.sqrt(x**2-1)
def f4(x):
  return np.sqrt(x**2-2)
s= np.arange(np.sqrt(2),5,0.05)
t=np.arange(1,5,0.05)
y1=f1(t)
y2=f2(t)
y3=f3(t)
y4=f4(s)
ax.plot(t,y1,'k-',t,y2,'k-',t,y3,'k-',s,y4,'k-')
plt.xlim([1.1,2.1])
plt.ylim([0.5,1.5])
plt.show()
```

I would like to fill the area between the curves described by those four functions. Not sure how to use the `fill_between` option in this case.

Comment: Do you want to fill the area between the lowest and the highest function? (per given point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `fill_between` two curves not four. So using the four curves that you have, you can create two curvers, `y5` and `y6` which I have shown below, and then use these to `fill_between` them. An example is shown below:

I have also ploted the individual functions using symbols so that it is easy to see the different new curves just created ...

```
import pylab as plt 
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure(num=1)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

def f1(x): return 1/x
def f2(x): return 2/x
def f3(x): return np.sqrt(x**2-1)
def f4(x): return np.sqrt(x**2-2)

t=np.arange(1,5,1e-4) # use this if you want a better fill
t=np.arange(1,5,0.05)
y1=f1(t)
y2=f2(t)
y3=f3(t)
y4=f4(t*(t**2>2) + np.sqrt(2)*(t**2<=2) ) # Condition checking

y5 = np.array(map(min, zip(y2, y3)))
y6 = np.array(map(max, zip(y1, y4)))

ax.plot(t,y1, 'red')
ax.plot(t,y2, 'blue')
ax.plot(t,y3, 'green')
ax.plot(t,y4, 'purple')

ax.plot(t, y5, '+', ms=5, mfc='None', mec='black')
ax.plot(t, y6, 's', ms=5, mfc='None', mec='black')

ax.fill_between(t, y5, y6, where=y5>=y6)

plt.xlim([1.1,2.1])
plt.ylim([0.5,1.5])

plt.show()
```